# Classification of time series - how to train one model using data from multiple location?

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series

I have data sources from weather sensors around multiple locations. I am trying to classify whether a certain event is occurring (simple binary classification). 
I have labeled data (1 mil. samples for each location - 15 minutes interval).

I assume that the event that i try to classify is very simple (many patterns occur in same ways on all locations)

I would like to make one model for all locations but also with the ability to generalize for the next locations that will be added.

Right now i am using simple BiLSTM network and the data is pre-processed with a rolling window like this:

```
    def create_dataset(self, dataset, look_back=1):
     dataX, dataY = [], []
     for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back - 1):
         a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), :]
         dataX.append(a)
         dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
     return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
```

My first thought is to pre-process each location with rolling window, concatenate all the data into one training set and shuffle before each epoch.

Do you think it is a good approach ? Can you suggest a better one ? Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I don't want to tell my model during the training the exact location because in the future when i would like to predict the event at a new location the current training would be biased towards some location.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want your model to know which location you are giving input from. So your input must somehow tell you which location you are sending data from. You can concatenate a location part of your data to the actual weather information, or use a more one-hot-encoding like `x=temperature*e_(loc)` in which `e_(loc)=(0,0,1,0,...)` for the third location. In the latter setup you can also feed the system with multiple temperatures (or other information) at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't want to tell my model during the training the exact location because in the future when i would like to predict the event at a new location the current training would be biased towards some location.

Comment: but as behaviour of weather is location-dependent this sounds fair to me. You could also toss out the location information for now. Then train one general weather model. Later on you can make a copy of this general model for all locations and finetune the network per location with only the data from that location.